# Continuations: can I serialize the continuation in an F# async workflow or C# async function?

Tags: c#, f#, android-asynctask, continuations

I want a serializable continuation so I can pickle async workflows to disk while waiting for new events. When the async workflow is waiting on a `let!`, it would be saved away along with a record of what was needed to wake it up. Instead of arbitrary in-memory `IAsyncResult`s (or `Task<T>`, etc.), it would have to be, for instance, a filter criterion for incoming messages along with the continuation itself. Without language support for continuations, this might be a feat. But with computation expressions taking care of the explicit CPS tranformation, it might not be too tricky and could even be more efficient. Has anyone tackled an approach like this?

Comment: Can you provide an example that can describe more about what you are looking for?

Comment: How about `async { let! x = GetSimulationStartTime(); let! y = GetSimulationStopTime(); return! y-x }`, where start and stop might be days apart, and I don't want to explicitly model the state machine `type AgentState = WaitingForStart | WaitingForEnd | Completed`

Comment: AFAIK there isn't even an ready-to-use option to serialize Qutoations/Expressions - no way you get this for the general case of an continuation (where you might capture a lot within the closure). Just think of it - you would need a way to serialize every Object no matter what. If you REALLY need it either implement it yourself (you *could* rewrite the async-workflow yourself with the option to save ISerializable waiting-states to disk) - or realy look into WF as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the `MailboxProcessor`, or `Agent`, type as a means of getting close to what you want. You'd could then use the [`agent.PostAndAsyncReply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370407.aspx) with a timeout to retrieve the current `AgentState`. As mentioned above, you'll need to make the objects you are passing around serializable, but even delegates are serializable. The internals are really unrelated to `async` computations, though. The `async` computation would merely allow you a way to interact with the various agents in your program in a non-blocking fashion.

[Dave Thomas](http://moiraesoftware.com/) and I have been working on a library called [fracture-io](http://github.com/fractureio/fracture) that will provide some out-of-the-box scenarios for working with agents. We hadn't yet discussed this exact scenario, but we could probably look at baking this in ... or take a commit. :)

I also noticed that you tagged your question with `callcc`. I posted a sample of that operator to [fssnip](http://fssnip.net/7U), but Tomas Petricek quickly [posted an example](http://fssnip.net/7V) of how easy it is to break with `async` computations. So I don't think `callcc` is a useful solution for this question. If you don't need `async`, you can look in [FSharpx](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FSharpx) for the `Continuation` module and the `callcc` operator in there.

Comment: Since `MailboxProcessor`/`Agent` is indeed the idea here, I am encouraged, but I admit I'm not quite following. The agent's internal state would have to be serialized as a delegate (which as you note is possible) _along with_ the criteria for waking it up again (i.e. the message(s) which its waiting for).

Comment: So you would need some way to inspect each item again, correct? That shouldn't be difficult. You're basically following the command pattern with CanExecute and Execute delegates. I'll get with Dave and see if we can hash this out soon-ish.

Comment: If I can get my head around it completely, I'd be happy to work on it with y'all. Though the fundamental weakness is likely to be that the serialized delegate means that no workflow could last longer than a  new deploy of the application, since the structure of the continuation might change completely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Windows Workflow Foundation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx

That's probably the technology you want, assuming the events/messages are arriving in periods of hours/days/weeks and you're serializing to disk to avoid using memory/threads in the meantime.  (Or else why do you want it?)

Comment: Perhaps too hasty a judgment, but I'm allergic to cats and XML. These workflows are more likely to last for seconds or minutes, but hours and days will be common enough. In many cases the work to be done on each event is tiny, but the overall "state machine" complex enough that it would be nice to just use async workflows, i.e. simple programming instead of hand constructed state machines or XML legos. Also, I wouldn't mind running under Mono.

Comment: In my opinion the word "workflows" doesnt fits with the async. I would prefer to use async only when I m doing some IO operation that I want to perform asynchronously and not to use them implement "workflows" as you can have other better abstraction to represent workflows

Comment: I've never really used Workflow Foundation, but I wonder if it would be possible to write a custom computation expression builder in F# that wraps Workflow Foundation, perhaps eliminating the need for XML?